# Creating NDVI from raster using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, raster-calculator, ndvi, code-review

I have to create NDVI's for multiple raster images, and so want to find out the most efficient way to do it.

The code below works, but I wondered if there was a more efficient way to do it?

````py
# Strip out the red and near infrared bands    
arcpy.CompositeBands_management(input_raster + r"\Band_3", "raster_red")
arcpy.CompositeBands_management(input_raster + r"\Band_4", "raster_nearir")

# Create the ndvi numerator and denominators 
arcpy.Minus_3d("raster_nearir", "raster_red", "numerator")

arcpy.Plus_3d("raster_nearir", "raster_red", "denominator")

# Set local variables
top = arcpy.sa.Raster("numerator")
bottom = arcpy.sa.Raster("denominator")

# Execute Divide
raster_ndvi = top / bottom

# Save the output
raster_ndvi.save("ndvi_result")```
````

Comment: Also, if anyone can explain how to use GenerateRasterFromRasterFunction to do this(see arc pro documentation [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/generate-raster-from-raster-function.htm)) I would be much obliged.

Comment: Ooops, sorry!  Thanks again for your assistance here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
from arcpy.sa import *

input_raster = 'path/to/raster'

red = Float(Raster(input_raster + r"\Band_3"))  
nir = Float(Raster(input_raster + r"\Band_4"))

ndvi = (nir - red) / (nir + red)

ndvi.save("ndvi_result")
```

You could also use `GenerateRasterFromRasterFunction_management`, but that seems to take much the same processing time

```
import time

from arcpy.sa import *

input_raster = r"c:\temp\LC80900812014223LGN00.TIF"  # Some Landsat 8 data

s = time.time()
red = Float(Raster(input_raster + r"\Band_4"))    # Band names are 1 indexed
nir = Float(Raster(input_raster + r"\Band_5"))

ndvi = (nir - red) / (nir + red)

ndvi.save("c:/temp/ndvitest1.tif")

print("Map algebra:", time.time() - s)

s = time.time()
arcpy.GenerateRasterFromRasterFunction_management(
    raster_function="NDVI",
    out_raster_dataset=r"c:\temp\ndvitest2.tif", 
    raster_function_arguments=r"Raster c:\temp\LC80900812014223LGN00.TIF; VisibleBandID 3;InfraredBandID 4;ScientificOutput 1",  # Bands are 0 indexed
    format="TIFF")
print("GenerateRasterFromRasterFunction:", time.time() - s)
```

```
Map algebra: 17.283000230789185
GenerateRasterFromRasterFunction: 17.730000257492065
```

Comment: Thanks @user2856, this is a lot more succinct than my code, but has more or less the same runtime.  Have you ever come across GenerateRasterFromRasterFunction - [arcpro raster functions](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/generate-raster-from-raster-function.htm)? And do you think it can be used for this purpose?

Comment: @AndrewEinhorn See edit

Comment: Thanks a million for the demonstration!  Try as I might, when I run the following code, I get an error.  Can you see where I'm going wrong?

`from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.GenerateRasterFromRasterFunction_management(raster_function="NDVI", out_raster_dataset=r"D:\output_image.tif", raster_function_arguments=r"Raster D:\input_image.tif; VisibleBandID 3; InfraredBandID 4; ScientificOutput 1", format="TIFF")`

arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000814: Invalid file type
ERROR 000840: The value is not a String
Failed to execute (GenerateRasterFromRasterFunction)

Comment: Looks ok to me, suggest you ask a new question and provide your code, the error, full details of the input raster, and whether you can apply the ndvi raster function manually via ArcGIS Pro (not GenerateRasterFromRasterFunction, just the function itself).